# MYOB Essentials Invoice API unable to push invoice

Tags: c#, json, myob

I am using RestSharp to push an invoice to MYOB.

```
RestClient myobPostInvoicesClient = new RestClient("https://api.myob.com/");                   
RestRequest myobPostInvoicesRequest = new RestRequest("au/essentials/businesses/" + business_uid + "/sale/invoices", Method.POST);
myobPostInvoicesRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
myobPostInvoicesRequest.AddHeader("x-myobapi-key", clientId);
myobPostInvoicesRequest.AddHeader("x-myobapi-version", "v0");
myobPostInvoicesRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

The JSON I am sending to the endpoint is as below

```
{{
  "contact": {
    "uid": "26939970"
  },
  "invoiceNumber": "IV00000000082",
  "issueDate": "2020-06-07T09:00:00",
  "dueDate": "2020-07-07T09:00:00",
  "gstInclusive": "true",
  "status": "Open",
  "lines": [
    {
      "unitOfMeasure": "Qty",
      "quantity": 5.0,
      "unitPrice": 1000.0,
      "total": 5000.0,
      "taxType": {
        "uid": "10"
      },
      "account": {
        "uid": "9"
      },
      "description": "Test Description"
    }
  ]
}}
```

The Response I am getting back from the MYOB Invoice API endpoint is

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"field\":\"\",\"message\":\"Forbidden\",\"code\":\"403\"}]}"
```

The access token and client id are both valid and I am following the structure of the Invoice based on the below link

https://developer.myob.com/api/essentials-accounting/endpoints/sale/invoices/

The ones I have included in the request where the fields that were previously marked as required but MYOB have modified the UI.

Just for reference I can GET contacts, accounts and taxtypes from MYOB, just getting the Forbidden 403 message back trying to POST an Invoice.

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use postman to test some Get calls... if they are valid, then try and use the option in postman to create c# code... find the difference and update your call.

Comment: I can get contacts, account and taxtypes from MYOB. They come back fine.

Comment: Then the account you are using most likely doesnt have rights to post data

Comment: Is there any page on MYOB you can reference where I can enable to POST permissions,?I haven't had this issue when Integrating with AccountRight.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 403 Forbidden, you need to check the permissions on the account that you are using to make the post call.

[See here](https://apisupport.myob.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000497295-User-Access-Permissions-and-Rights-) to read about the permissions of the account

Except from link above

**How do I check a user's access permissions**

To find out exactly what rights the current user has, and to ensure they have the right permissions for your application to function correctly make a GET request to the {{company_file_uri}}/{{company_file_id}}/CurrentUser endpoint.

Following response tells you what permissions the user has on each url

```
{
    "UserAccess": [
        {
            "ResourcePath": "https://{{company_file_uri}}/{{company_file_id}}/Banking/BankAccount/",
            "Access": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "ResourcePath": "https://{{company_file_uri}}/{{company_file_id}}/Banking/ReceiveMoneyTxn/",
            "Access": [
                "GET",
                "POST",
                "PUT",
                "DELETE"
            ]
        },
      ...
    ]
}
```